# Какими знаками лучше оформить вставку?

Tags: пунктуация, вставная-конструкция

> А знаете, они тут такой трюк придумали! Знаете, как они тренера
>   недавно разыграли? Видно, ночами репетировали **– на прошлом
>   представлении они прикололись –** поменялись голосами! Белуха
>   открывала рот во время пения, а подавала голос афалина! Тренер чуть в
>   воду от удивления не свалился, а эти хихикали там по-своему,
>   понимаете?

И вторую:

> И когда их привозят, **ну только из моря – они сначала наблюдают за
>   нами и только потом вступают в осознанный контакт –** что радует
>   человека, то и делают.

Так?

*И когда их привозят – ну только из моря, – они сначала наблюдают за нами и лишь потом вступают в осознанный контакт: что радует человека, то и делают.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В первом абзаце "видно, ночами репетировали" должно быть вставкой или отдельным предложением, а основная мысль: на прошлом представлении они прикололись - поменялись голосами. Поэтому предлагаю два варианта:

**Знаете, как они тренера недавно разыграли? Видно, ночами репетировали, а на прошлом представлении прикололись – поменялись голосами.**

**Знаете, как они тренера недавно разыграли? На прошлом представлении прикололись – поменялись голосами (видно, ночами репетировали).**

Во втором абзаце "ну только из моря" - это вставка, то есть подходит такой вариант:

**И когда их привозят – ну только из моря(,) – они сначала наблюдают за нами и лишь потом вступают в осознанный контакт: что радует человека, то и делают**

Не уверен по поводу запятой после "моря", может она "поглощается"?